# Python Uncertainties Unumpy type bug?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, types

I am having a hard time with pythons uncertainties package. I have to evaluate experimental data with python, which I've been doing for a while but never encountered the following problem:

```
>>>from uncertainties import ufloat
>>>from uncertainties import unumpy as unp
>>>u = ufloat(5, 1)
>>>l = unp.log(u)
>>>print(l)
1.61+/-0.2
```

Everything seems to be all right, right? But here comes the strange part:

```
>>>print(type(l))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Which is a **huge** problem because this is how I encountered it:

```
>>>print(l.n)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Right now in my work I desperately need the nominal values and standard devivations separately for linear regressions. What's really strange about this and makes me think it actually is a bug is the fact, that printing the variable actually works like intended but python "thinks" its type is an array when its actually supposed to be an ufloat.

Any ideas or tips for an easy workaround? Do you think it is a bug or did I miss anything and it is actually my mistake?

To prevent anybody from asking why I am doing such an easy calculation: That's just an example of course. In my actual work I have many many much more complex values stored in arrays.

Edit1: https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html

Edit2: 
Ok here is the code I am actually having problems with, the above was just supposed to illustrate the problem.

```
d, t, n = loadtxt('mess_blei_gamma.txt', unpack=True)
fh = open('table_blei.txt', 'w')
nn = []
ln = []
for i in range(0, len(d)):
    nn.append(norm(n[i], t[i], n0))
    ln.append(unp.log(nn[i]))
    fh.write(tex(str(d[i])+" & "+str(t[i])+" & "+str(n[i])+" & "+str(nn[i])+" & "+str(ln[i]))) #works how it's supposed to, the table is perfectly fine
fh.close()

print(unp.nominal_values(nn)) #works fine
print(unp.nominal_values(ln)) #error
```

Comment: can you please clarify what you what to l.n to be?

Comment: l is supposed to be of type ufloat. In general if you have u of type ufloat then u.n is the same as u.nomina_value. So e.g. u = ufloat(5, 1) then u.n hast to be 5 and u.s = u.std_dev has to be 1.

Comment: check out my post, I corrected it after your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, many unumpy objects are basically numpy arrays:

```
>>>arr = unp.uarray([1, 2], [0.01, 0.002])
>>>arr
[1.0+/-0.01 2.0+/-0.002]
>>>type(arr)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

so you should not be surprised.
 By the way, ufloat is a function and not a type:

```
>>>x = ufloat(0.20, 0.01)  # x = 0.20+/-0.01
>>>print type(x)
<class 'uncertainties.Variable'>
>>>type(ufloat)
<type 'function'>
```

Secondly, in order to get the nominal values you should use:

```
unumpy.nominal_values(l)
```

EDIT:
After you edited your original message, I think I understand your problem. You can use unumpy.log outside the for loop like this:

```
>>>nn = [ ufloat(1, 2), ufloat(53, 4)]
>>>ln = unp.log(nn)
>>>ln
[0.0+/-2.0 3.970291913552122+/-0.07547169811320754]
>>>type(ln)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>>(unp.nominal_values(ln)) #now it works fine
[ 0.          3.97029191]
```

I also agree that this behavior is a bit weird.

A code that runs well and achieves your goal:

```
d, t, n = loadtxt('mess_blei_gamma.txt', unpack=True)
fh = open('table_blei.txt', 'w')
nn = (norm(n[i], t[i], n0) for i  range(0, len(d)))
ln = unp.log(nn)
for i in range(0, len(d)):
    fh.write(tex(str(d[i])+" & "+str(t[i])+" & "+str(n[i])+" & "+str(nn[i])+" & "+str(ln[i]))) #works how it's supposed to, the table is perfectly fine
fh.close()

print(unp.nominal_values(nn)) 
print(unp.nominal_values(ln))
```

Comment: Yes I know about that, but that does not has anything to do with my Problem. I am going to edit my question in order to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Oh thank you even more, did not know that this usage of for loops was possible in python. I am really a python nooby :D

Comment: I am not sure I see how "this behavior is a bit weird": NumPy math functions applied on a single float do not return a float. So do unumpy math functions. Functions for arrays are essentially intended for arrays (not for floats, even though there are connections between both for 1-element array).

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the uncertainties package.)

The math functions from the `uncertainties.unumpy` module are for *NumPy arrays* that contain numbers with uncertainties (in the same way as one uses `numpy.log` on arrays because `math.log` is not meant to work on arrays).

In your example you instead want the log of a simple *float* with uncertainty:

```
>>> from uncertainties import ufloat
>>> u = ufloat(5, 1)
```

[There are dedicated functions for this](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html#mathematical-operations) in the `uncertainties.umath` module (which is the equivalent of the standard `math` module):

```
>>> from uncertainties.umath import log
>>> log_value = log(u)  # This is a UFloat, like u (and not a 1-element array)
>>> print log_value.n  # Nominal value, as expected
```

What you observe is similar to what NumPy does when you use its math functions on Python scalars:

```
>>> numpy.log(3)
1.0986122886681098
>>> type(_)  # Not a Python float!
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```